# Rails 3. How to setup Devise to look at the email column in a model that User inherited from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a model called Person. I want User to inherit from Person.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end

class User < Person

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable

  # for some reason I HAVE TO user attr_accessor on the following attributes or
  # else I would get noMethodError or something like that, I'll fix this later
  attr_accessor :username, :encrypted_password, :locked_at, :current_sign_in_at, :last_sign_in_at, :current_sign_in_ip, :last_sign_in_ip, :sign_in_count

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
    :first_name, :last_name, :mobile_phone, :phone_one, :phone_two, :organization_id

  validates :username, :presence => true
end
```

Now I'm installing Devise and it wants to create the `users` table with an `email` column. But I don't want that `email` column because User is supposed to inherit `email` from Person.

I want the User model inherit from the People model. People already has an `email` attribute, so User doesn't need it anymore.

How can I make Devise look at the `email` column on the `people` table instead of the `users` table **for the lockable module and whenever Devise needs to send an email**?

Can I just remove the `email` column from the migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it look for the person email you would do `User.email` and just remove the email from devise's user table migration.

You will also want to remove the email validations https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L24

Comment: Since User is inheriting from Person, wouldn't `User.email` suffice?